# problems with mysql pdo query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is there something wrong with my query?

```
function needExport($table, $key, $id, $stamp) {
    try {
        $dbW = dbConCC();
        $stmt = $dbW->prepare("SELECT * FROM :table LIMIT 10");
        $params = array(':table' => "tmlaender");
        $stmt->execute($params);
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            echo $row;
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo json_encode($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

I get the follwoing Syntax Error:

```
"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''tmlaender' LIMIT 1' at line 1"
```

Can't find any mistakes in this "simple" query.

Comment: Why `:table` with `:`?

Comment: Because it's an placeholder?

Comment: Table and Column names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
function needExport($table, $key, $id, $stamp) {
    try {
        $dbW = dbConCC();
        $stmt = $dbW->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table`");
        $stmt->execute();

        $fetch = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        return $fetch;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

then when echoing a field from table you'd simply:

`$var1 = $var->needExport();`

`echo $var1->idColumn;`

**Note:**

Binding Params is only used when using a `WHERE` such as:

```
public function getId($userid)
{
    $dbW = dbConCC();
    $stmt = $dbW->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `userid` = :uid");
    $stmt->bindParam(':uid', $userid);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: My pet hate is - votes with no note as to why someone has decided to - vote it.

Comment: It looks like table isn't replaced: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ccweb.table' doesn't exist

Comment: You need to change `table` to your table name

Comment: Ok, but tbale name comes as variable "$table". But I read that it's not possible to prepare the table name and columns

Comment: what is your tablename called? tmlaender?

Comment: for example...I will use the same query for diffrent tables. So I decide to wrap it in this function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130677/discussion-between-option-and-robert).

Comment: My pet hate is an answer that doesn't answer the question asked